# "Compare" program for Eclipse preference files

Tags: python, parsing, eclipse

I am trying to write a simple (trivial?) "compare" program for Eclipse preferences files.

Eclipse preferences files take more of less this form:

> ```
> # optional comment line
> /a/sequence/of/path/elements=string
> /another/sequence/of/path/elements=42
> # ... (possibly repeated)
> ```

Let's call the path sequences "keys" and what follows the `=` sign "values".

The rules of the program should be:

- Exit upon detecting an invalid # of arguments (must be 2)
- argument1 and argument2 are the files to compare
- Exit if any of the input files are empty
- One preference entry per line
- Lines with a path key will have a path value, guaranteed

The output should be as follows:

#### Part 1

- All lines from argument1 which have keys not present in argument2, like so:

  > ```
  > /path 42
  > /path2 banana
  > ```
- Blank line

#### Part 2

- All keys that are present in both argument1 and argument2, like so:

  > ```
  > /shared (valueInArgument1, valueInArgument2)
  > /shared2 (valueInArgument1, valueInArgument2)
  > ```
- Blank line

#### Part 3

- All lines from `argument2` which have keys not present in `argument1`, like so:

  > ```
  > /path3 24
  > /path4 ananab
  > ```

Notice Part 1, Part 2, and Part 3 must all be sorted.

I would like to get something:

- Pythonic
- Efficient (do as little work as possible computationally, use as little space as possible)
- Clear and readable from a logical point of view
- Correct (gets the right result even in edge cases)
- Instructive (uses data structures and algorithms properly)

Here's my attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /opt/local/bin/python2.7

import sys
import os
import re
import pprint

COMMAND_SYNTAX_ERROR = 2
EMPTY_PREFS_FILE_ERROR = 3

PREFS_REGEX_PATTERN = '^(.*?)=(.*)$'
PREFS_REGEX = re.compile(PREFS_REGEX_PATTERN)

def parse_prefs_line(line):
  regex_result = PREFS_REGEX.match(line)
  if not regex_result:
    return None, None
  return regex_result.group(1), regex_result.group(2)

arguments = sys.argv
n_arguments = len(arguments)

if n_arguments != 3:
  print 'usage: eclipse_diff file1.epf file2.epf'
  sys.exit(COMMAND_SYNTAX_ERROR)

file1, file2 = open(sys.argv[1]), open(sys.argv[2])

prefs1 = file1.readlines()
file1.close()

prefs2 = file2.readlines()
file2.close()

length1, length2 = len(prefs1), len(prefs2)

if length1 == 0 or length2 == 0:
  print 'both files must contain at least one configuration line'
  sys.exit(EMPTY_PREFS_FILE_ERROR)

prefs1.sort()
prefs2.sort()

onlyin1 = []
onlyin2 = []
inboth = []

index1 = 0
index2 = 0

stop1 = False
stop2 = False

pause1 = False
pause2 = False

lastkey1 = None
lastkey2 = None

while True:

  if not stop1 and not pause1:

    line1 = prefs1[index1]

    if not line1:
      stop1 = True
    else:
      line1_left, line1_right = parse_prefs_line(line1)
      if line1_left and line1_right:
        onlyin1.append((line1_left, line1_right))
        lastkey1 = line1_left
      index1 += 1
      if index1 == length1:
        stop1 = True

  if not stop2 and not pause2:

    line2 = prefs2[index2]

    if not line2:
      stop2 = True
    else:
      line2_left, line2_right = parse_prefs_line(line2)
      if line2_left and line2_right:
        onlyin2.append((line2_left, line2_right))
        lastkey2 = line2_left
      index2 += 1
      if index2 == length2:
        stop2 = True

  if lastkey1 and lastkey2:
    if lastkey1 == lastkey2:
      inboth.append(
        (lastkey1,
          (onlyin1.pop()[1], onlyin2.pop()[1]
        )))
      lastkey1 = onlyin1[len(onlyin1)-1][0] if onlyin1 else None
      lastkey2 = onlyin2[len(onlyin2)-1][0] if onlyin2 else None

  if not stop1:
    if lastkey1 and not stop2 and lastkey1 > lastkey2:
      pause1 = True
    else:
      pause1 = False

  if not stop2:
    if lastkey2 and not stop1 and lastkey2 > lastkey1:
      pause2 = True
    else:
      pause2 = False

  if stop1 and stop2:
    break

for pref in onlyin1:
  print pref[0], pref[1]
print
for pref in inboth:
  print pref[0], pref[1]
print
for pref in onlyin2:
  print pref[0], pref[1]
```

How can I improve this?

To make my question specific: I would like for it to execute in less cycles.

My other thought was to create a hash map of keys, add values to it, sort the keys and split the output based on how many values correspond to the key...

Comment: Where's the profiler output?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You are still working on your algorithm.  Once you get an algorithm you are happy with, then optimize it, not before.  Your "PS" comment sounds like a good direction to me.  Give that a try.

Comment: Actually no, I have decided against the hash map in the end and this is what I have got as my algorithm. I think this is superior to the hash map approach. I may be mistaken. Do you think differently? Why?

Comment: @mhawke: a good pointer. I did not know about that... Still in Beta though, no wonder I did not have it at the top of my list.

Comment: Haven't used it personally, but perhaps this would be relevant? http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't optimize unless your profiler says so.

You could start with the simplest code that works e.g., here's a straightforward translation of your requirements:

```
import sys

def get_entries(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        # extract 'key = value' entries
        entries = (map(str.strip, line.partition('=')[::2]) for line in file)
        #note: if keys are repeated the last value wins
        # enforce non-empty values, skip comments
        return {key: value for key, value in entries
                if value and not key.startswith('#')}

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    sys.exit(2) # wrong number of arguments
d1, d2 = map(get_entries, sys.argv[1:])
if not (d1 and d2):
    sys.exit(1) # no entries in a file

def print_entries(keys, d, d2=None):
    for k in sorted(keys):
        value = d[k] if d2 is None else "(%s, %s)" % (d[k], d2[k])
        print k, value
    print

print_entries(d1.viewkeys() - d2.viewkeys(), d1)
print_entries(d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys(), d1, d2)
print_entries(d2.viewkeys() - d1.viewkeys(), d2)
```

You could compare results and the performance with your code.

You could also compare it the [`comm` command from coreutils](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/comm.c#n229):

```
$ comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```